# Unable to install deb packages

Tags: apt, package-management

this morning I tried to install app slimbookamdcontroller, but installation didn't go well and I was left with this error. So, when I try to install any other deb package I am getting the same error. I tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, but the error is the same. Any ide how to fix this?
Thanks

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  slimbookamdcontroller stremio
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 6672 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 195768 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing slimbookamdcontroller (0.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/slimbookamdcontroller.postrm: 9: cd: can't cd to /usr/share/s
limbookamdcontroller/
dpkg: error processing package slimbookamdcontroller (--remove):
 installed slimbookamdcontroller package post-removal script subprocess returned
 error exit status 2
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 slimbookamdcontroller
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try to remove the both packages with dpkg

Comment: I tried tp execute this `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq slimbookamdcontroller` but got this error `(Reading database ... 195768 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing slimbookamdcontroller (0.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/slimbookamdcontroller.postrm: 9: cd: can't cd to /usr/share/slimbookamdcontroller/
dpkg: error processing package slimbookamdcontroller (--remove):
 installed slimbookamdcontroller package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 slimbookamdcontroller
` any idea what else to try?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit].

Answer (score 0):

After executing this command `sudo ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i <package name>` and deleting all files, everything worked fine...

Comment: Please add more information to question and to answer. Points for highlight - packages source, your distro version, which instruction do you follow and why.